# Calculating the similarity between 2 sentences

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, math, levenshtein-distance

I would like to calculate the similarity between 2 sentences and I need the percentage value which says "how good" they match with each other. Sentences like,

```
1. The red fox is moving on the hill.
2. The black fox is moving in the bill.
```

I was considering about `Levenshtein distance` but I am not sure about this because it says it is for finding similarity between "2 words". So can this `Levenshtein distance`help me or what other method can help me? I will be using JavaScript.

Comment: Can't you treat the sentence as a bag of words and run Levenshtein on each one of them? Plus I think this would be on-topic on CS.SE (implying that I think it's off-topic here)

Comment: @rath: This is not off topic. Just like this, I have asked number of questions about CV algorithms and Speech Recognition algorithms.

Comment: The levenshtein distance is simply the minimum amount of operations (delete/replace/insert) on string #1 to get to string #2. A space counts as an operation. It's not only for words.

Comment: I thought Levenshtein distance was for finding the similarity between two _sentences_...?

Comment: I'm familiar with the *Hamming* distance, Levenshtein is new to me

Comment: @h2ooooooo: So, basically does that mean it really doesn't matter whether it is a "sentence" or a "word" ?

Comment: @Hope No, it doesn't matter, however it won't think that `This is a super long string` is very similar to `string` (it'd require 21 delete operations), but compared to `foo` (which would require 24 delete operations and 3 replace operations) it scores lower.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: hmm..I am not 100% clear about your last comment. Can you explain a bit please?

Comment: @Hope As mentioned, levenshtein distance is the amount of operations it takes to get from string 1 to string 2. Hence if `This is a super long string` should be turned into `string` we'd require 21 delete operations (first we delete the first character, then the second, then the third etc.). `foo` would require 24 delete operations (so there's 3 characters left) and 3 replace operations (as none of the letters we need are there). Hence `string` would have a levenshtein distance of 21, but `foo` would have one of 27 (hence less alike).

Comment: @h2ooooooo: ahh.. So that means the "matching percentage" between `This is a super long string` and `string` is `(5/27)*100` am I correct? The 5 is the length of `string` and 27 is the length of `This is a super long string`

Comment: @Hope That wouldn't check content, but only length though. If you want a percentage, you might be looking for something similar to [this JS port of PHP's similar_text](http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text/) that can return a percentage.

Comment: What do you mean by similarity? By purely lexicographical measures, your second sentence is more similar than, say, "The *Vulpes vulpes* moves across the hill," but my sentence is closer in *meaning*. If you consider meaning, then lexicographical measures aren't very useful.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Hi, OK so you have mentioned ` levenshtein distance is the amount of operations it takes to get from string 1 to string 2`. So this is a code sample in JavaScript - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#JavaScript
According to your comment, I need to pass the `This is a super long string` as the first parameter and `string` as the second parameter. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

Try this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kAZwB/33/) for `JS string diff`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, but I am looking more into a algorithmic solution so I can using in any language. I am using JS. Your solution might be correct, but highly language dependable.

Comment: Hi Hope,   wait 5 min I will give you a java script function for the same

Comment: Hope visit above solution link

Answer (score 1):

Use [Jaccard index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). You can find implementations in any language, including JavaScript ([here](https://github.com/ecto/jaccard) is one, didn't test it personally though).

Answer (score 0):

this is what i would do depending on how important this is. if this is medium to low priority here is a simple algo.

1. scan all sentences and see how often a word occurs.
2. filter out the most common words like the ones in 30% of sentences , i.e. don't count these. so at the as would hopefully not be counted.
3. then do your bag of words comparison.

But the context in why you want to do this is really important. i.e. the example you gave us could be for students learning english etc. i.e. theres different algorithms i would use if i was trying to see if crowd sourced users are describing the same paragraph vs if article topics are similar enough for a suggested reading section.

Answer (score 0):

A common Method to compute the similarity  of two sentences is to cosine similiarity. Don't know if there an implemenatation in JavaScript exists. The cosine similiarity looks on words and not of single letters. The web is full of explenations for example [here](http://www.blog.computergodzilla.com/2012/12/what-is-cosine-similarity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for an HTML page that does what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Phrase Similarity Calculator</title>
    <script>
        function calculateSimilarity() {
            var phrase1 = document.getElementById("phrase1").value;
            var phrase2 = document.getElementById("phrase2").value;
            
            // Calculate similarity percentage
            var similarity = calculateLevenshteinDistance(phrase1, phrase2);
            var similarityPercentage = similarityToPercentage(similarity);
            
            // Display the result
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The similarity percentage is: " + similarityPercentage + "%";
        }
        
        function calculateLevenshteinDistance(phrase1, phrase2) {
            // Levenshtein Distance calculation
            var distance = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <= phrase1.length; i++) {
                distance[i] = [];
                distance[i][0] = i;
            }
            for (var j = 0; j <= phrase2.length; j++) {
                distance[0][j] = j;
            }
            for (var i = 1; i <= phrase1.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 1; j <= phrase2.length; j++) {
                    var cost = (phrase1.charAt(i - 1) === phrase2.charAt(j - 1)) ? 0 : 1;
                    distance[i][j] = Math.min(
                        distance[i - 1][j] + 1,         // Deletion
                        distance[i][j - 1] + 1,         // Insertion
                        distance[i - 1][j - 1] + cost   // Substitution
                    );
                }
            }
            return distance[phrase1.length][phrase2.length];
        }
        
        function similarityToPercentage(similarity) {
            var maxLength = Math.max(document.getElementById("phrase1").value.length, document.getElementById("phrase2").value.length);
            var percentage = ((maxLength - similarity) / maxLength) * 100;
            return percentage.toFixed(2);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Phrase Similarity Calculator</h1>
    <label for="phrase1">Phrase 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="phrase1" placeholder="Enter phrase 1"><br>
    <label for="phrase2">Phrase 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="phrase2" placeholder="Enter phrase 2"><br>
    <button onclick="calculateSimilarity()">Calculate Similarity</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can test it here ( until the link expires ):

https://onecompiler.com/html/3zmakmwy5